# Why does \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top} not work here?

Tags: captions, floatrow

Why does `\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}` not work here?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

% Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
\newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{%
\rule{30pt}{40pt}
}{%
  \caption{A figure}%
}
\capbtabbox{%
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
                            \toprule
    A & B & C \\ \midrule
    1000 & 100 & 900          \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}{%
  \caption{A table}%
}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to add an image of what you see and perhaps what you expected to see. I see no real output difference if I switch to the `article` class.

Comment: Thanks. I just found a way to solve it with \newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[\captop][\FBwidth] but the alignment wrong.

Comment: @daleif I did that too but it didn't work.

Comment: Again you have not explained what the end goal is? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @daleif I want to put the table caption on top and keep aligmenent same (the bottom alignment here)

Answer (score 3):

It works if you use the right command, which is `\ttabbox`:

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{floatrow}
    \floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

    % Table float box with bottom caption, box width adjusted to content
    \newfloatcommand{capbtabbox}{table}[][\FBwidth]
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}

    \blindtext
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{floatrow}
    \CenterFloatBoxes
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{PepeLePew}
    }{%
      \caption{Pepe le Pew}%
    }
    \ttabbox{%
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
                                \toprule
        A & B & C \\ \midrule
        1000 & 100 & 900 \\ \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    }{%
      \caption{A table}%
    }
    \end{floatrow}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see. I used a different approach in my comment above and got the same result. However, how can I keep the bottom alignment?

Comment: Do you mean align the table bottom and the figure bottom?

Comment: yes, currently it looks bad.

Comment: @hana: I'll try to see if there's a solution. I tried via `\ floatsetup{…}`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Adding `\CenterFloatBoxes`  at the beginning of the `flatrow`makes it look much better,, albeit not quite like you'd want to have it.

Comment: Yea, that looks much better though I still want to make some more alignment.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use `floatrow` and those complicated settings.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}


\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\columnwidth}
\centering
  \rule{30pt}{40pt}

  \caption{A figure}

  \vspace{0pt}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\columnwidth}
\centering
  \captionof{table}{A table}

  \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
  \toprule
  A & B & C \\
  \midrule
  1000 & 100 & 900 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{0pt}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The trick is adding `\vspace{0pt}` at the bottom, so this becomes the reference point for the bottom aligned minipages.

[image]

Comment: Nice, I got something similar from my previous question but using the caption package changes my default setting like it converts to "Table:" which is not what I want. And first time seeing someone with that high point on stack exchange.

Comment: @hana `caption` is *not* compatible with `IEEEtran`

Comment: how about cap-of? Is it compatible with IEEEtran? Is there any tip to check if something is not compatible with IEEEtran?